# How to implement an image gallery inside an Activity mimicking the Android's default gallery?

Tags: android, gallery

I want to implement an activity inside my Android app which will show all photos that are inside the smartphone.

I searched everywhere for how to do it but all I found was tutorials suggesting to use Intent.ACTION_PICK . **but  I want to show it inside a activity** in my app and not by calling other app in the smartphone.
any suggestions or hint of how to do it or how to implement my own gallery ?

Comment: There is no "Android's default gallery". There are thousands of Android device models. There will be hundreds of "default gallery" implementations on those, as manufacturers usually implement their own (and, sometimes, several of them). Beyond that, you need to explain, **in detail**, what it is that concerns you about implementing a gallery.

Comment: You need to use an Intent to find the photos then load them as needed.